# Listagem de aniversários num intervalo de datas

Tags: sql-server

Está me a dar um erro quando faço esta query para comparar o dia e o mes de aniversario no sql `format(data,'MM-dd')` . 
preciso de tirar da data o mês e o ano e fazer um between

```
Select NUMERO,DATA from utilizadores where  format(DATA ,'MM-dd') between '12-30' and '01-02'
```

pretendo é fazer uma listagem de aniversários o format não funciona em algumas versões do sql

Outro erro que dá é quando muda o ano

Comment: Qual é o objetivo da consulta? // Você cita "esta query" mas na descrição não consta nenhum código T-SQL. // Para facilitar a proposição de respostas, sugiro que acrescente informações sobre a tabela e as colunas diretamente envolvidas nesta consulta, bem como exemplo.

Comment: fazer uma listagem de aniversarios... com intervalos de datas de dias defenidos pelo utilizador

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso:

```
-- código #1 v5
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set @DataInicial = cast(Current_timestamp as date);
set @DataFinal = @DataInicial;

-- verifica se é sexta-feira
set datefirst 7; -- domingo como primeiro dia da semana
IF datepart(weekday, @DataInicial) = 6
  set @DataFinal = DateAdd(day, +2, @DataInicial);    

--
declare @Ano1 int, @Ano2 int;
set @Ano1= year(@DataInicial);
set @Ano2= year(@DataFinal);

--
IF (@Ano1 = @Ano2)
  begin
  SELECT NUMERO, Convert(char(5), DATA, 103) as [Dia/Mês]
    from utilizadores 
    where DATA < @DataInicial
          and Cast(DateAdd(year, (-year(DATA) + @Ano1), DATA) as date) between @DataInicial and @DataFinal 
    order by month(DATA), day(DATA)
  end
else
IF (@Ano1 < @Ano2)
  begin
  SELECT NUMERO, Convert(char(5), DATA, 103) as [Dia/Mês]
    from utilizadores 
    where DATA < @DataInicial 
          and (Cast(DateAdd(year, (-year(DATA) + @Ano1), DATA) as date) >= @DataInicial 
               or Cast(DateAdd(year, (-year(DATA) + @Ano2), DATA) as date) <= @DataFinal)
    order by month(DATA), day(DATA)
  end;
```

Optei por utilizar variáveis do tipo date para definir o período de emissão, pois isto facilita tratar virada de mês e de ano. A data de nascimento do utilizador é atualizada para o ano do período de emissão e então é verificado se está no período.

Supondo que o período de emissão seja de 1/2/2017 a 10/2/2017, e se o utilizador de número 8 nasceu em "19/9/1960", a data é transformada em "19/9/2017" e então comparada com as datas de limitação do período:

```
se "19/9/2017" está entre "1/2/2017" e "10/2/2017"
     então "é aniversariante";
```

Comment: a data está neste formato 1960-09-19 00:00:00.000

Comment: @usersantos: Indica que a coluna DATA está declarada como datetime. Testou o código #1 v3?

Comment: é isso mesmo funciona

Comment: basicamente vai servir para listagem de aniversarios hoje, caso seja uma sexta feira apresenta os de sabado e domingo. Só uma coisa para que serve esta funcção DateAdd(year, (-year(data) + @Ano1), data)

Comment: @usersantos - Alterei o código #1 para obter a data corrente e definir automaticamente a data final, considerando-se se é ou não sexta-feira. // O trecho que perguntou altera o ano de nascimento para o ano da data limite, permitindo a comparação direta de intervalo. Por exemplo, transforma "19/9/1960" em "19/9/2017" e verifica se está no período de emissão.

Answer (score -1):

Tente filtrar ano e mês conforme exemplo abaixo!

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

DECLARE
    --@ANO  INT;
    @MES    INT;

--SET   @ANO    = 2017;
SET @MES    =   2; -- fevereiro


SELECT
    U.NUMERO,
    U.DATA

FROM
    UTILIZADORES U

WHERE
    -- DATEPART(YEAR, U.DATA) = @ANO
    DATEPART(MONTH, U.DATA) = @MES;
```

Comment: o format da-me erro. em algumas versões do sql.

Comment: o datepart mete o mes 2 apenas... falta o 02 quando depois vou comparar

Comment: Não havia entendido direito.... editei a resposta!
Poderá escolher o ano e mês que desejar.

Comment: se mudar o ano não funciona isso dá apenas para um dia

Comment: Editei... filtrando apenas o mês para qualquer ano.

Comment: eu quero ter uma listagem entre duas datas... dia e mes

Comment: se fizer de um ano para outro dá barraca

Comment: Para dia, utilize `datepar(day, data);`