# Comparação de dia e mês no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

Preciso filtrar numa consulta todos os clientes que tem data de aniversário entre duas datas informadas. Como posso fazer uma comparação de datas desconsiderando o ano cadastrado no cliente?

A consulta atual está assim:

Parâmetros informados: Data Inicial:29/04, Data Final:05/05

```
Where Convert(datetime,
        Convert(varchar, DAY(cli.DataNascimento)) + '/' +
        convert(varchar, MONTH(cli.DataNascimento)) + '/1900', 103)
    >= convert(datetime, '29/04/1900', 103)
And Convert(datetime,
        Convert(varchar, DAY(cli.DataNascimento)) + '/' +
        convert(varchar, MONTH(cli.DataNascimento)) + '/1900', 103)
    <= convert(datetime, '05/05/1900', 103)
```

Porém esta consulta está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
Mensagem 242, Nível 16, Estado 3, Linha 1
A conversão de um tipo de dados varchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo.
```

Tem alguma forma melhor de fazer essa consulta?

Comment: Como você sabe que a **maior** data deve estar no ano de 1900?

Comment: Todas as datas estarão no ano de 1900 pois não quero considerar o ano, dessa forma converto todas as datas para o mesmo ano

Comment: Não poste 'Solução' em uma pergunta, acho que não faz sentido.

Comment: @Pilati  veja solução proposta em **Listagem de aniversários num intervalo de datas** -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185192/listagem-de-anivers%c3%a1rios-num-intervalo-de-datas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Verificamos que o problema era o dia 29 de fevereiro cadastrado na data de nascimento de alguns clientes. Como o ano 1900 não é um ano bissexto dava erro na hora de converter `29/02/1900` para data. Sendo assim o filtro ficou da seguinte forma:

```
Where 1=1
    And Convert(datetime, Format(cli.DataNascimento, 'dd/MM') + '/1904', 103) 
        >= convert(datetime, '10/05/1904', 103)  
    And Convert(datetime, Format(cli.DataNascimento, 'dd/MM') + '/1904', 103) 
        <= convert(datetime, '12/05/1904', 103)
```

Answer (score 2):

Considerando-se que a coluna DataNascimento esteja declarada como *datetime*, a sugestão é que a cláusula WHERE fique assim:

```
WHERE cast(dateadd(year, -year(cli.DataNascimento) % 1900, cli.DataNascimento) as date) between @DataInicial and @DataFinal
```

Eis a contextualização:

```
-- código #1
--> informe data inicial e final
declare @DataInicial date, @DataFinal date;
set @DataInicial= convert(date, '29/4/2018', 103);
set @DataFinal= convert(date, '5/5/2018', 103);

-- ajuste interno para 1900
set @DataInicial= dateadd(year, -year(@DataInicial) % 1900, @DataInicial);
set @DataFinal= dateadd(year, -year(@DataFinal) % 1900, @DataFinal);

SELECT ...
  from ... as cli
  where cast(dateadd(year, -year(cli.DataNascimento) % 1900, cli.DataNascimento) as date) between @DataInicial and @DataFinal;
```

Comment: Propus uma outra solução em tópico semelhante. Veja **Listagem de aniversários num intervalo de datas** -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185192/listagem-de-anivers%c3%a1rios-num-intervalo-de-datas

Answer (score 1):

Eu aconselho rever como é passado o parâmetro, pois conceitualmente falando para se pesquisar entre datas você precisa receber datas, no caso você está deduzindo de alguma forma as datas.

Até é possível fazer essa busca se fixar `1900` como data inicial e o ano atual como data final(pois não tem como ninguém ter nascido no próximo ano).

O desempenho dessa busca será péssimo considerando que você vai trazer praticamente tudo, provavelmente não mudará muito entre uma busca sem a condição de data no `where`.

**Exemplo:**

```
SET @param1 = @param1 + '/1900'
SET @param2 = @param2 + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

Sua condição `where`:

```
WHERE 
   cli.DataNascimento >= CONVERT(datetime, @param1 , 103)
   AND  cli.DataNascimento <= CONVERT(datetime, @param2 , 103)
```

**Exemplo aplicado em um procedure:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O ano de 1900 foi definido justamente pois não quero considerar o ano, assim coloquei todas as datas no mesmo ano, só quero comparar o dia e o mes

Answer (score 1):

Eu simplificaria um pouco a lógica adicionando a quantidade de anos que faltam para o ano corrente na data de nascimento do cliente. Uma vez que estivesse recebendo como parametro as datas de inicio e fim considerando o ano atual, seria uma comparação de datas simples.

Veja só:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, cli.DataNascimento,GETDATE()), cli.DataNascimento) 
    BETWEEN 
        CAST('20180429' as datetime) // Data inicial do período buscado
        AND 
        CAST('20180505' as datetime) // Data final do período buscado
```

Como um pequeno teste de mesa, podemos usar um cliente nascido em `14/10/1990`. Então, segmentando a lógica teríamos:

```
// Datas como string no formato YYYYMMDD

DATEDIFF(YEAR, '19901014',GETDATE()) 
// Resultado: 2018 - 1990 = 28

DATEADD(YEAR, 28 , '19901014')
// Resultado: 14-10-2018

// Agora bastou comparar:
'20181014' BETWEEN CAST('20180429' as datetime) AND CAST('20180505' as datetime)
// O resultado é: False
```

Espero ter ajudado.